# Getting MalFormed Xml error while uploading large files to S3 using aws amplify resumable uploading

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

Error :

> AWSS3UploadTask - error completing upload MalformedXML: The XML you
> provided was not well-formed or did not` validate against our
> published schema

Code :

```
export async function uploadVideoFile(file, progressChange) {
  const fileName = `${file.name}`;
  const dirName = 'xyz'
  const key = `${dirName}/${fileName}`;


  // return;
  try {
    const upload =  await Storage.put(key, file ,{
      resumable: true,
      errorCallback(err){
        console.log(`my error : ${err}`);

      },
      progressCallback(prog) {
        console.log((prog.loaded / prog.total) * 100)
        progressChange((prog.loaded / prog.total) * 100);


      },
    }
    
    
    );
    return upload
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`storage error : ${err}`);
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add

ETag in Expose Headers in S3 bucket CORS configuration

```
<ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Chetan Khanna 's answer above just add it in JSON in 2022:

```
 "ExposeHeaders": [
             "ETag",
             "x-amz-meta-custom-header"
  ]
```

taken from:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/cors.html

Answer (score -1):

In my case i was missing some required parameters in the `param` object and solved my problem